# nhibernate legacy database extra columns

Tags: nhibernate

I have legacy database. 
I need to add nhibernate but for several columns in a table.
How can I make nhibernate not to complain that there are no properties for some columns.
In the future it is possible that new columns will be added, but they are not needed in my project.
How can I do this ?

Regards,
Darko

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any problems if those database columns are *nullable*, or if they have *default values*. When you think about it, the same is true when you are trying to do an SQL INSERT on a table.

Just map the columns that you need to properties of a class.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to read, do no map them;

Otherwise, if you need to write in them, you will need to map them (if they are not nullable or do not have default values), in order to provide the values needed by the database.